# Как записать число 600851475143 в переменную на языке Си?

Tags: c

Нужно переменной присвоить значение 600851475143, но ни один из типов данных языка Си не подходит. Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64-битные числа никто не отменял, [[@Иван Кущёв](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long i = 600851475143LL;
    printf("%lld\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: c90 не гарантирует наличие `long long`. Это может иметь значение, если используется старая версия Visual Studio на Виндах, которая плохо поддерживает c99, который гарантирует наличие `long long` и что его размер по меньшей мере 64-bit (можно попробовать "%I64" и `__int64` в этом случае).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте другой компилятор, в котором есть 64-битные типы данных. Или ключи у существующего.

Answer (score 0):

Или использовать две переменные, в одной хранить n старших разрядов, а в другой - N-n разрядов, где N - общее число разрядов числа.